# Конвертация Bitmap в icon Android API 17

Tags: java, android, api, bitmap, icon

Нужно провернуть такую конвертацию

```
notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(bitmap));
```

Только вот `Icon.createWithBitmap` это API 23, а мне нужно с API 17. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

До 23 API нет возможности выставить маленькую иконку с помощью `Bitmap`, `Notification.Builder` нужно именно `Resource Id`, даже если вы сделаете:

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

Он всё равно выдаст ошибку, потому что этого `Drawable` нет в пакете приложения.

Comment: Тогда вопрос. Как сделаны приложения которые выводят в строку состояния допустим температуру? Они ведь по идеи должны писать в bitmap, а затем постоянно выводить его в строку состояния? И такие приложения как то работают с API 17

Comment: А зачем вам тогда нужна маленькая иконка? setLargeIcon не подходит?

Comment: setLargeIcon  не отображается в строке состояния

Comment: А, вот вы о чём

Comment: Может они хранят иконки на все случаи жизни и подменяют их в зависимости от ситуации?

Comment: Похоже именно так.......

Answer (score 1):

Сам класс [`Icon`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Icon.html) был добавлен только в Api 23, соответственно и работать с ним на версиях ниже невозможно.

Остаётся надеяться, что появится какой нибудь `IconCompat` в support library который будет доступен на нижних версиях (а может и не появится, потому что если бы хотели/могли, то уже давно бы бекпортировали).